# Conexión BD con PHP y MYSQL

Tags: php, mysql, poo

Por favor una ayuda con mi intento de conexión a BD. He terminado un proyecto web y todo el tiempo estuve desarrollándolo en mi máquina SIN TENER NINGÚN PROBLEMA de conexión a la BD local sin embargo cuando he subido el proyecto al hosting final, no he podido lograr la conexión. El código que he utilizado para esto es:

```
function conectarDB(): mysqli
{
    $mysqli = new mysqli('host', 'usuario', 'password', 'bd');
    $mysqli->set_charset("utf8");

    if (!$mysqli) {
        echo "Error, no se pudo conectar al servidor";
        exit;
    }
    return $mysqli;
}
```

Este código está en un archivo llamado database.php dentro de la carpeta "config" que está dentro de mi carpeta "includes".

Ya en mi index.php intento conectarme con lo siguiente:

```
require 'includes/config/database.php';
$db = conectarDB();

?>
```

Los datos de conexión con los que intento conectarme son correctos ya que intenté realizar la conexión de la forma mysqli_connect() y sí logré hacerlo, sin embargo necesito conectarme de la primera manera ya que todo el site está programado con POO pero por alguna razón, estando el proyecto ya en el hosting final, no me los reconoce. No solo me pasa con el tema de conexión si no con todas mis demás funciones. Como comenté líneas arriba, no creo que sea problemas de error en el código porque el proyecto corre muy bien cuando lo tengo de forma local en mi pc. Realiza las consultas a la BD y obtiene los resultados esperados sin embargo ya en el hosting eso no sucede. Alguien sabe porqué me puede estar sucediendo esto? Muchas gracias.

Comment: Cual es el error que obtienes?

Comment: No es como que el código sea incorrecto, pero es *incapaz* de decirte lo que realmente esta mal ya que esta limitado a un mensaje genérico, que para esto caso no es muy clarificador

Comment: Para ayudarte necesitamos mas detalles, puedes empezar por [aqui](https://www.php.net/manual/es/mysqli.error.php#refsect1-mysqli.error-examples) guiate de los ejemplos de la doc. para que obtengas el mensaje de error real y sobre el trabajemos.

Comment: Asumiendo que es Windows el OS de desarrollo, MySQL/MariaDB se comportan insensibles a mayúsculas y lo contrario pasa cuando es Unix/Linux (como la mayoría de los hostings). Verifica TODO tu proyecto que los nombres de archivos estén exactos y lo mismo con todos los nombres de bases de datos, tablas y columnas.

Comment: Ya descubrí el error. Para este proyecto estaba probando un proveedor de hosting nuevo. Resulta que el php que estaba instalado en este hosting era de una versión muy antigua, además que no estaba activa la extensión mysqli. Probé el proyecto con mi proveedor de siempre y funcionó. Ahí me di cuenta. Ya lo estoy arreglando con el proveedor nuevo. Muchas gracias por sus comentarios.